# Branching my own project from github, then pushing it back to github with branches intact

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-remote

This feels like im missing something obvious, but i've been reading tutorials for 3 days and can't seem to make it happen.

I have a private repo on github. I want to run it as two separate branches. As I understand it, I clone the repo so its on my local machine, then branch it using

git branch newbranch

git checkout newbranch

so far so good. Now i make some changes, commit to newbranch. It seems like I can push this all to my remote repo intact, but I'm having trouble doing it without simply merging it with master, which is not what I want to do. How can I put my branches on github intact?

Is this the correct workflow for doing this? If it is, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just:

```
 git push origin mybranch
```

should be enough; it will push the HEAD of the current branch you are in (not master, but the one you are working on) to a similary named branch. if the remote branch has not the same name, then

```
git push origin mybranch:remotebranch
```

[`git push`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) uses a refspec to specify with what `<src>` object the `<dst>` ref in the remote repository is to be updated.

Comment: I think`git push origin mybranch` would push mybranch, no matter what's the current branch, to origin. not HEAD of current branch.

Comment: @jsvnm but the premise of the question was that `'mybranch'` was checked out. `HEAD` references mybranch (called '`newbranch`' in the OP's question). Note that the push policy might change with Git2.0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782825/git-config-that-gets-cloned/11783210#11783210

Answer (score 5):

this will only push the newbranch to origin/newbranch on github:

```
git push origin newbranch:newbranch
```