# git config that gets cloned

Tags: git

The goal is so after doing `git clone git@somewhere:something.git`

The resulting `something/.git/config` will contain

```
[push]
    default = tracking
```

without requiring the cloner to do `cd something; git config push.default tracking` so he/she won't accidentally push all branches when pushing without argument (No, nobody reads the README).

Comment: You can provide a shell script which sets the option automatically. Git provides no way to do so, because the config file might contain dangerous aliases or options.

Comment: @knittl Can the script be included in the repo, and be run automatically when the repo gets cloned? Like post-clone hook or someting?

Comment: You can include it in the repository, but you cannot have it executed automatically. Think about the security implications this would cause!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is difficult to enforce policy on the downstream or client side (which is dangerous, as [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl) comments), the upcoming **Git 2.0** recognizes that fact and will change the default push policy.

<sup>(The discussions on this date from early 2012, as illustrated in "[`git push` current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9749535/6309)")</sup>

It will go from the current default one:

> **`matching`** - push all branches having the same name in both ends.
>   This is for those who prepare all the branches into a publishable shape and then push them out with a single command.
>   **It is not appropriate for pushing into a repository shared by multiple users**, since locally stalled branches will attempt a non-fast forward push if other users updated the branch.
>   **This is currently the default, but Git 2.0 will change the default to `simple`**.

To the new one, called "**`simple`**":

> `upstream` - push the current branch to its upstream branch.
>   With this, `git push` will update the same remote ref as the one which is merged by git pull, making push and pull symmetrical. See "`branch.<name>.merge`" for how to configure the upstream branch.
>
> **`simple`** - like upstream, but refuses to push if the upstream branch's name is different from the local one.
>   **This is the safest option and is well-suited for beginners**. It will become the default in Git 2.0.